# I want to sort only odd numbers in an array in ascending order and leaving even numbers at their orignal place in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

[image]

Below is the code in image where i have sorted array in ascending order
but i am unable to sort only odd numbers, leaving even number at their original place like below
[**5**, 8, 6, **3**, 4]  =>  [**3**, 8, 6, **5**, 4]

Comment: Please paste code, and not an image of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key aspect you need to consider is that to ignore even numbers in array and apply your sorting algorithm at odd numbers only.
Here's the implementing using bubble sort:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {5, 8, 6, 3, 4};
    int i, j, n=a.length;
    
    for(i=0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i]%2 != 0) {
            int toPlace = i;
            for(j=i+1; j < n; j++) {
                if (a[j]%2!=0 && a[i] > a[j]) {
                    toPlace = j;
                }
            }
            int temp = a[toPlace];
            a[toPlace] = a[i];
            a[i] = temp;
        }
    }
    
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```

PS: Try building on this intuition for nlogn sorting.